# Gridview buttons

Tags: android, button, gridview

I am trying to fix my button click events and right now I have every button reacting the same. I want each button to ultimately do something different. My code currently is:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button myButton;

    if (convertView == null) {
        myButton = new Button(mContext);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(230, 150));
        myButton.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        convertView = myButton;
    } else {
        myButton = (Button) convertView;
    }

    myButton.setText(mButtons[position]);
    myButton.setId(position);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position));
    return convertView;
}

class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private final int position;
    final MediaPlayer mpButton1Click = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,
            R.raw.myAudio);

    public MyOnClickListener(int position) {

        this.position = position;

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = v.getId();

        if(position == 0){
        mpButton1Click.start();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm currently using a media player but that might change. I know I need to pass in the individual button positions probably in the onClick() method but I can't figure out how to do that (or if there is an easier way). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have already done it: you have added `setId(position)`. So in your *OnClickListener*: use `int position = v.getId();`. Voila, you've got your position.

Comment: Just get your position int position = v.getId(); like @SherifelKhatib has mentioned inside your onClick() implementation.

Comment: Ok I understand that. Now what do I do with `position` once I use it in onClick. I edited my code by the way

Comment: Of course they all react the same: you always call the `mpButton1Click` variable no matter what position is.

Comment: @vorrtex yes I realize that, I just don't know how to use the position variable because you can't pass it into start()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a tag for each button, you will be able to differentiate them.

```
button.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position);
```

On the onClickListener you just have to do this :

```
Integer position = (Integer)view.getTag();
```

Comment: So do I even need to have my own onClickListener?

Comment: No, because the position is given by the tag view. And you have access to it in the classic listener, it's the parameter.

Comment: Ok I'm confused at to what you mean by On the onClickListener add the position variable. Do I need to use it in the onClick?

Comment: There are two things, 
1. You can either use you own code where you have extended OnClickListener and use position like @SherifelKhatib has suggested. 
2. Or you can just implement an onClickListener and use the views tag suggested by Shemsu